# How to send email from a custom domain when using Messaging.SingleEmailMessage

Tags: email

I am sending email by creating a `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage` object and then using `Messaging.send()`.

The emails are being sent out successfully, but the `from` address is a very long url with a big id followed by `.salesforce.com`, which doesn't look great.

Is there any way to set the `from` address to be my company's custom domain?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apex email : How to override 'From address'](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5964/apex-email-how-to-override-from-address)

Comment: @tugce - It does. I missed that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FROM Email address can be changed by adding and verifying an organization-wide address. While the email can be sent out by setting an Organization-wide address, there are additional steps to be taken that to ensure that the emails are received by everyone if the sender compliance is enabled.

Make sure that your company has added [SPF/DKIM](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=emailadmin_setup_dkim_key.htm) keys as CNAME's to validate the sender and make sure that your email addess cannot be spoofed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Manjit. Very helpful.