# Sending case emails from queue email address by default

Tags: email, case, email2case

Salesforce sets the from address as each users own address by default. This means that responses from the clients go to the users own mailbox, not salesforce.

Instead, we would like the from address to be set as an email to case queue address by default so that responses are captured by the queue and processed directly into salesforce.

I can't find a way to do this though. I was able to make buttons that set the p26 parameter (the from address), but I can't find a way to override the reply/to all/send email buttons in the email message related list.

Answer (score 2):

There's an idea up on the idea exchange asking Salesforce to implement this. 
My org has the same problem. 
Vote it up.

[link to idea on success.salesforce.com](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kdRmAAI)

AFB

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is no button click method for this, you will have to use Apex to send the email. Here is a similar question [Setting a from address in SingleEmailMessage](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1243/setting-a-from-address-in-singleemailmessage)

it uses the  SingleEmailMessage apex method within which you can set the reply to email address

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm

oh wait after all that i actually read the question :(

send email button overrides are under Customize | Activities | Activity Buttons however it looks as though they only support S-Controls and not visual force pages like other objects do.

Answer (score 0):

From memory, if you set up an organization wide email address with the same email address as your email2case email address, it becomes an option within the picklist of from email addresses on the send email screen.  With the organization wide email address, when a user replies to an email it usually picks the right one from the list instead of the user's email address.
This doesn't force the user to use the correct email address, but makes it less likely they'll use their personal email address.

This is something I set up a fair few years ago and my memory of it is a bit fuzzy, so it's possible my recollection may not be right.

Answer (score 0):

See Richard Fleming's comment on page 3 here -- https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kdRmAAI -- with the Case Feed enabled, you can force an org-wide email address as the default, or provide a list of valid reply-to addresses.

Comment: Just FWIW that's specific to Service Cloud and the Case Feed, not the standard Email activity related list.

Answer (score 0):

To just keep this question up to date, Salesforce has released an option to set the default 'from address' in quick action "Send Email" (or whatever name of send email quick action in your org)

Goto Setup --> Object Manager --> Case --> Buttons, Links, and Actions --> Open the quick action of type sendEmail added on your page layout (if multiple such actions then check which one is added on desired page layout) --> Add default 'from address' in the predefined field values. You can set 'From Name' too.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Sorry to raise this from the dead.

I've been struggling with this in my instance, but have found a workaround by having users set their default from address to be the OWA.

Works perfectly for us, and you can still select your own address if necessary.

Downside is that you have to get every user to do it.