# Change status of lead using Trigger?

Tags: trigger

I need to write Trigger when the Status of a Lead changes ? I'm wondering whether this will work or not . Thanks in advance.

Comment: When do you want to change the status? On insert, update, delete? What would be the reason/trigger for changing it and do you know the value that you want to change it to?

Comment: When LeadStatus field is Updated then it should fire the trigger.It can be both after or before update. No, i do not the value of change.

Comment: Wait, first you ask how to change the status of the lead, but then you're saying that changing the status should trigger something... Can you please elaborate on this a bit more? :)

Comment: Mistake Barchovski.:) .Question updated.

Comment: All good :) What are you trying to achieve when the status of the lead changes? It is possible though. Let me know so that I can provide you with more detailed answer.

Comment: Ok. When the Status of a Lead changes, a notification should be sent from the Owner of THAT Lead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can achieve that via workflow and an email template, but it is also possible via trigger as well. Setting up a workflow/email template is pretty straight forward - [a good example.](http://www.newfangled.com/creating_salesforce_workflow_rules)

And if there is a reason you can't go with the workflow this is the trigger (code hasn't been actually run and tested, you might need to tweak it a bit):

```
 trigger Lead on Lead (after update)
{
    Map <Id, String> leadsOwner = new Map <Id, String> ();

    // Go through every lead in the trigger
    for (Lead lead : trigger.new)
    {
        // Check if the status has been changed
        if (lead.Status != trigger.oldMap.get(lead.Id).Status)
        {
            // get the owner ID's that have been affected
            leadsOwner.put(lead.ownerId, null);
        }
    }

    // Map the owner ID to it's email address
    for (User owner : [SELECT Id, Email FROM User WHERE Id = :leadsOwner.keySet()])
    {
        leadsOwner.put(Id, Email);
    }

    List <Messaging.SingleEMailMessage> emails = new List <Messaging.SingleEMailMessage> ();

    // Go again through every lead in the trigger
    for (Lead lead : trigger.new)
    {   
        // Only work with leads that have owners mapped to their email addresses (only those ones have their status changed)
        if (leadsOwner.get(lead.OwnerId) != null)
        {
            // Create an email message and add it to the list
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); 
            List <String> toAddresses = new List <String> {leadsOwner.get(lead.OwnerId)};
            mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses); 
            mail.setSubject('Automated Email : Lead Status Updated'); 
            String body = 'The status has been changed on the lead record with ID ' + lead.Id; 
            mail.setPlainTextBody(body); 
            emails.add(email);
        }
    }

    // Send out the emails 
    Messaging.sendEmail(emails);
}
```

Note that you have a limit of number of emails that you can send through APEX in your organisation. It is not very efficient way of doing this - [email limits.](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm#email_limits_section)

I would be trying to do anything to send the emails via workflow.

Comment: Is it possible to send notification through trigger? Much better if you can sample me the exact trigger.Pressing my head :)

Comment: Under notification you mean an email?

Comment: Yes an email should be sent.

Comment: Updated the answer mate

Comment: I am having trouble compiling it. It's saying : Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: Id at line 19 column 24 . I think it should work.

Comment: Replace id with owner.Id

Comment: Oh yes i already did that.Help appreciated.Also for Email , it will be owner.Email.

Comment: Exactly right! Good luck

Comment: i was wrong with my req.The email that is sent is to the Owner only. But the req is the email should go from Owner to the Leads.Any pointers please

Comment: You can send it to the lead by replacing this :             `List <String> toAddresses = new List <String> {lead.Email};` but there is no way to set the FROM address. It will always be the organization wide email address

Comment: Can i not use setOrgWideEmailAddressId(Id) to achieve? I really appreciate your knowledge but i'm curious to know in my case .:)

Comment: You can but it won't be dynamic. Here is an answer on how to do that - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1243/setting-a-from-address-in-singleemailmessage

Comment: I used it but what is happening is, the email is not sending from Owner to Lead. So lets say Owner Name is "Joseph" and Lead name is "Lead 1" and the email add is Bachovski@salesforce.com. The email goes to Lead but in From its Joseph only.Is this becaue OWA i set my email add?  In From it should come Bachovski.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16301/discussion-between-bachovski-and-jjoseph).