# SingleEmailMessage setReplyTo not working with some clients

Tags: singleemailmessage

Even though the `ReplyTo` property of SingleEmailMessage is set to a "noreply" address we are still getting emails sent to our admin email. This only happens with certain email clients (e.g. Gmail doesn't do it).

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage e = buildEmail();
e.setSenderDisplayName('noreply@company.com');
e.setReplyTo('noreply@company.com');
```

The email that goes out of SF has the following sender:

> noreply@company.com < adminuser@company.com >

The email that comes to us from user has this in its recipient field:

> "noreply@company.com" < adminuser@company.com >

So in this case the "noreply" address is being treated as the label.

Is there a way to fix this? Or do I need to log a case with SF?

Answer (score 1):

There's probably nothing Salesforce can do about it. As far as I can tell, the `setReplyTo()` method is functioning correctly and is setting the `Reply-To` value on the envelope.

You could try [Setting a from address in SingleEmailMessage](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1243/setting-a-from-address-in-singleemailmessage), which should work even if the email client ignores the `Reply-To` address.