# Remove "reply to" in apex Messaging.SingleEmailMessage

Tags: apex, email

We have a apex trigger that send mails.
In this mails, we can see:

```
reply_to_email@fmm65sbh16h2kh67.xxwomdonwmb2otze.3p1x6n6.1j-8cbreaq.cs102.bnc.sandbox.salesforce.com
```

How can remove this **`reply to`**"?

I checked this article, but it does not work: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000167022&type=1

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1243/setting-a-from-address-in-singleemailmessage

Comment: That email address part of the [Bounce Mail Management](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_bounce_mail_management.htm&type=5) feature. Disabling that should also remove this Reply To address.

Comment: @AdrianLarson This is not the duplicate you think it is.

Comment: Are you saying it is a duplicate of some other post? Or not a duplicate at all?